# Написал код, для вывода количества положительных элементов. В чем ошибка?

Tags: java, массивы

```java
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int size = 10;
        int[] myArr = {1, 8, -24, -3, 0, 2, 7, -8, -9, 3};
        int[] rez = new int[size];
        for (int v : myArr)
            System.out.print(v + " ");

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (myArr[i] >= 0) {
                rez[i] = myArr[i];
            }
        }
        int s = rez.length;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

Объясните ошибки...

Answer (score 0):

```
int countPositive = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (myArr[i] > 0) {
        countPositive++;
    }
}

System.out.println(countPositive);
```

Comment: Человек попросил указать, что за ошибки были. Можно было бы объяснить.

Answer (score 0):

Вы создаете массив фиксированной длины `size`, который наполнен значениями по дефолту(`0` для `int`). Далее копируете лишь те ячейки из другого массива в соответствующую ячейку первого, которые >= 0. Потом получаете длину ФИКСИРОВАННОГО ПО ДЛИНЕ массива, которая равна `size`, который вы указали изначально. Итого его наполнение будет следующим:

> {1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 0, 0, 3}

Решение - введите переменную, с помощью которой считайте кол-во ячеек, которые > 0. Сделать это можно способом, который предложил Igor.

Answer (score 0):

На стримах значительно меньше кода получается. Считаем количество элементов, больше нуля:

```java
int[] arr = {1, 8, -24, -3, 0, 2, 7, -8, -9, 3};

long count = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(i -> i > 0).count();

System.out.println(count); // 5
```